# url in json, jquery ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, response

```
{
    "imgsrc":"http:\/\/192.168.1.181\/postcardthis\/facebook\/angel_wall.jpg",
    "message":"asdf",
    "friend":"Friend1",
    "error_message":""
}
```

This my `JSON`, here `imgsrc` location seems difficult, two slashes. what to do to convert perfect URL?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`jQuery.parseJSON( json )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). It is available as of jQuery 1.4.

> Description: Takes a well-formed JSON
>   string and returns the resulting
>   JavaScript object.

You should be able to do:

```
var myObj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"imgsrc":"http:\/\/192.168.1.181\/postcardthis\/facebook\/angel_wall.jpg","message":"asdf","friend":"Friend1","error_message":""}');
alert(myObj.imgsrc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to eval your JSON string:

`var js = eval(json_string);`

Then, the imgsrc property in js will have your URL:

`js.imgsrc;`